# Does anyone know how to configure a Wacom Bamboo tablet to work left-handled?

Tags: tablet

I have my Wacom Bamboo tablet working fine under Fedora 14 but would like to switch it from right- to left-handed.

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by left-handed? You want applications on the right and shutdown on the left?

Comment: I mean write on the tablet using my left hand with all the tablet buttons on the right-hand side (so they're not pressed accidentally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [xsetwacom](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index.php/howto/xsetwacom).

Basically, you'll want to list your current configuration, then re-configure the buttons to be the opposite way around, e.g. what button 1 did, button 4 should be (or whatever).

You could also try using `xinput`.

Something like:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 2FG Finger pad               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 2FG Finger touch             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]

$ xinput get-button-map "Wacom Bamboo 2FG Finger pad"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

$ xinput set-button-map "Wacom Bamboo 2FG Finger pad" 3 2 1 4 5 6 7
```

Do you also need to remap the x and y axes?

Final thought: what happens if you go to System->Preferences->Mouse?  Maybe changing it to left handed has some effect?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above suggestion. It solved a slightly different problem for me:

I configured my regular mouse to be left-handed, and wanted to use the Wacom tablet right-handed.  The problem was that the tablet now interpreted pen/touch clicks as 'right-clicks', following the mouse setting - thus displaying the context menus etc.

The following worked:

```
xinput set-button-map "Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch" 3 2 1 4 5 6 7
xinput set-button-map "Wacom Intuos PT S Pen stylus" 3 1 2 4 5 6 7
```

Note: I had previously tried:

```
"xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT S Pen stylus" button 1 button 3"
```

-- which did NOT work in my set-up

(using KDE 5.14.0/Wacom Intuos Pen and Touch)